# OpenLayers upgrade document moving from 5.3.0 to 6.6.1

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm looking for documentation that will explain the breaking changes going from the latest version 5.3.0 release to 6.6.1...I'm sure that the new code is AMAZING!!!...but not if you have hundreds of errors and don't know what the new version is looking for or any documentation that explains how to fix these errors?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the list of releases and changes within each release.
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases

Comment: Thank you...I've looked through this but it does not address the errors I'm seeing in code after upgrading.  for instance I create an array of features Array<olFeature> and the error is "Generic type 'Feature<Geometry>' requires 1 type argument(s)" ... I don't know what to do with this or what it wants and it's not documented as far as I can see?

Comment: Essentially it seems that these are Typescript errors which seems to continue to plague OpenLayers and // @ts-ignore is not a solution to this